# Is it possible to share same hibernate-cfg file between different portlets?

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere-portal

I am developing different spring portlets that uses hibernate library, I have added the hibernate-cfg.xml file under src folder for each portlet which is working fine, but this file is same across all portlets, so is there is a way to put this file in shared location that all portlets can see.

**Note**: I have added all hibernate table mapping files and all hibernate code in one JAR in a shared library and it is working fine, but only hibernate-cfg.xml can be seen only when I copy it individually in each portlet and when I try to put it in same shared library jar, it is not seen by the portlets.

Comment: the shared library jar, are you adding that to portal, or to, the portlet applications themselves.  If you place it in the shared-app directory all portlets should see it by default

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have configured new shared library on the Websphere application server, and referenced this shared library to my portlets. so the jar not in the portltes but the hibernate-cfg not seen by the portlets.

Comment: in the past I have done it as a portlet service that calls the hibernate and all the portlets call the portlet service